# Write how manu characters left in textbox

Tags: javascript

I have a textbox with a max value of 10, and I want #pid p tag to write the number of remaining characters.

html:

```
<textarea id="content" maxlength="10"></textarea>
<p id="pid">max 10 chars</p>
```

javascript:

```
var content = document.getElementById('content');

var pid = document.getElementById('pid');

function charsLeft() {

    for (var i = 10; i >= 1; i--) {

    contentCount = 10;

    pid.innerHTML = parseInt(contentCount - 1);

    }

}

content.onkeypress = charsLeft;
```

All i managed to do is that when I start typing, i see 9, but as I keep typing it stays as 9.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/duxAj/)

I want to do this with pure JS, no libraries.

Comment: Are you making a joke?  You subtract 1 from 10 and you're surprised you get 9 over and over?

Comment: I hoped because of the loop first contentCount would be 9, so 9-1=8, then 8, so 8-1 and so on.

Comment: Because you put `contentCount = 10` **inside** of the for loop, it gets set to 10 every loop. This is why you always get 9.

Comment: You actually wrote `contentCount = 10`.  The computer is responsive to what you write, but not, sadly, to what you hope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function charsLeft() {
    pid.innerHTML = content.value.length > 0 ? content.getAttribute("maxlength") - content.value.length + " chars left" : "max 10 chars";
}
content.onkeyup = charsLeft;
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/duxAj/4/).

Comment: Why not using "textContent"? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.textContent

Comment: I knew I was complicating it.

Comment: @dzumla011 Yeah, you don't need a loop for this.

Answer (score 1):

## **jQuery**

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    var text_max = $('#content').attr('maxlength');
    $('#pid').html(text_max+' characters remaining');
    
    $('#content').keyup(function(){
     var text_length =$('#content').val().length;
     var text_remaining =text_max - text_length;
    // alert(text_remaining + ' ' +text_length + ' ' +text_max);
     $('#pid').html(text_remaining+' characters remaining');
    });
});
```

Comment: I was hoping to do it with pure JS, but I'll see from this jquery if I can do it.

Answer (score 1):

You could work with "keyup"-Event

```
document.getElementById("mybox").addEventListener("keyup", calcRemainingChars)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XHgQy/

Answer (score 1):

Well your error is that you redeclare your comment count each time you call your function. You have to make your comment count a global variable.

A fix of your version to count characters:

```
var content = document.getElementById('content'),
    contentCount = 10;

function charsLeft() {
    var pid = document.getElementById('pid');

    for (var i = 10; i >= 1; i--) {
    pid.innerHTML = parseInt(contentCount - 1);

    }

}    
content.onkeypress = charsLeft;
```

I do not, however; suggest you to make a global variable for counting the amount of characters. In your method 'backspace' is not considered giving an inaccurate count. The way I would suggest you to count the amount of characters is to call the 'length' member.

My suggestion

```
var content = document.getElementById('content');

function charsLeft() {
    var pid = document.getElementById('pid');
    pid.innerHTML = (content.value.length > 0 ? content.value.length + " chars left!" : "max 10 chars");
}
content.onkeypress = charsLeft;
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/duxAj/3/)